# Power BI brings inaccurate data

Tags: powerbi

Working on a dashboard I use cards to show the total amount of budget and the total worked area. With these two amounts I calculate the cost per area. Suddenly, this cards show wrong calculations.

To find out what was going on, I created a new page and placed new cards with the data described above and the calculations were ok. So what I did is just to delete the previous cards and copy paste the new ones, and the result were the correctly calculated amounts.

So I wonder why this happened? I looked for any filters and none were applied to the original cards.
Please help! I dont want this to happen again. Thank you in advance!

Comment: You'll need to give us more information than that. What values are you calculating, and how are you doing so?

Comment: It could be changes in the data model, the measure, or changes in the refresh mode. For a good answer, please provide the measure, a view of the data model or - in the case of a table - a quick view of the data. If you don't want to provide those that is absolutely fine, table headers & linkage between the tables would do. Thanks and good luck!